Объединить два раздела диска
Всем доброго времени суток!
Раньше на ноуте были установлены Windows и Ubuntu.
Сегодня после моих "успешных" манипуляций с Ubuntu там пропали почти все стартовые приложения.
Решил, что это и есть знак, что поставить новую версию Ubuntu. Скачал образ, загрзил на флэшку, всё ок.
Рассчитывал, что новая версия накатится на раздел диска, где уже есть Ubuntu, перезапишет и всё будет замечательно.
Но после установки понял, что новая вресия накатилась не поверх старой, а ещё рядом. То есть мой диск теперь разделён на раздел с Windows, а раздел под Ubuntu поделён ещё на два раздела (скриншот прикладываю).
Вопрос: как можно экологично и безопасно удалить раздел со старой версией Ubuntu и отдать эти 80ГБ в раздел с новой версией.
Спасибо!


Что вы имеете в виду под словом «безопасно»? Вам какие-нибудь данных из обоих убунт сохранять надо или нет?

Нет, заново переустановлю

Тогда проще всего тупо удалить оба раздела и не заморачиваться

Если удалить оба раздела есть же риск того, что grub перестанет работать и тогда вообще windows не загрузишь?

Ну если вы собираетесь переустановить убунту, значит заодно переустано́вите и grub тоже
